# Setting SCNNode geometry property

Tags: ios, scenekit

I've got a SCNNode and I'm applying to it a geometry from a .dae file using this method:

```
func addNode(gridPosition: SCNVector3, row: Int, gamePlaneHeight: Float, sceneArray: [ObjectInfo]) -> SCNNode {

    // Create a material using the model_texture.tga image
    let carMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    carMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "assets.scnassets/Textures/model_texture.tga")
    carMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = false

    // Create a clone of the Car node of the carScene - you need a clone because you need to add many cars
    var carNode: SCNNode!
    let randomNumb = AppDelegate().randRange(0, upper: sceneArray.count - 1)
    let selectedObject = sceneArray[randomNumb]
    carNode = selectedObject.objectscene.rootNode.childNodeWithName(selectedObject.objectname, recursively: false)!.clone() as SCNNode

    carNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.5, AppDelegate().randomBetweenNumbers(0.8, secondNum: 2.2))
    carNode.name = selectedObject.objectname
    carNode.position = gridPosition
    carNode.position.y = carNode.position.y + gamePlaneHeight

    // Set the material
    carNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = carMaterial

    return carNode
}
```

The method works most of the time, but occasionally it crashes on the line

```
carNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = carMaterial
```

with the error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
```

I don't understand why, as most of the time it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`carNode` is built from `selectedObject.objectname`.
If `selectedObject.objectname` does not exist in the scene then `childNodeWithName` will return `nil`. Because `carNode` is an implicitly unwrapped optional, Swift will try to unwrap `nil` and crash.

You should make `carNode` optional (`var carNode: SCNNode?`) or add tests such as `if carNode == nil { ... }` and try to debug what your input (`selectedObject`) is and why it's incorrect.